# несколько sql запросов Insert подряд

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.x, sqlite3

при попытке запуска кода ниже:

```
сonn = sqlite3.connect("All APIs.db", timeout = 20)
db_s = conn.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO all_purchase_history VALUES(1, "build", 'response', 'today')"""
db_s.execute(query)

query = """INSERT INTO all_purchase_history VALUES(3, "build", 'response', 'today')"""
db_s.execute(query)

conn.commit()
```

Получаю

```
OperationalError: database is locked.
```

Как избежать ошибки при отправки нескольких запросов в БД. При том, что селекты работают без ерроров

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python SQLite: database is locked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2740806/4279)

Comment: Возможно, стоит почитать про atomic: http://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/db/transactions.html
Это поможет отправлять запросы по очереди.

Comment: проще сделать 1 структуру и закидывать ее одним insert- ом